# How to detect speech start on iOS Speech API

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition

I have an iOS app developed in XCode/objective C.
It uses the iOS Speech API to process continuous speech recognition.
It is working, but I want to turn the mic icon red when speech starts, I also want to detect when speech ends.

I implement the interface SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate which gives the callback onDetectedSpeechStart and speechRecognitionTask:didHypothesizeTranscription:  but these do not occur until the end of the first word is processed, not at the very start of the speech.

I would like to detect the very start of the speech (or any noise). I think it should be possible from the installTapOnBus: from the AVAudioPCMBuffer but am not sure how to detect if this is silence versus noise that could be speech.

Also the speech API does not give an event when the person stops talking, i.e. silence detection, it just records until it times out. I have a hack for detecting silence by checking the time between the last event fired, not sure if their is a better way to do this.

Code is here,

```
    NSError * outError;
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&outError];
    [audioSession setMode: AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement error:&outError];
    [audioSession setActive: true withOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&outError];

    SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest* speechRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];

    if (speechRequest == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to create SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest.");
        return;
    }

    audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
    AVAudioInputNode* inputNode = [audioEngine inputNode];

    speechRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true;

    // iOS speech does not detect end of speech, so must track silence.
    lastSpeechDetected = -1;

    speechTask = [speechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest: speechRequest delegate: self];

    [inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize: 4096 format: [inputNode outputFormatForBus:0] block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer* buffer, AVAudioTime* when) {
        long millis = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
        if (lastSpeechDetected != -1 && ((millis - lastSpeechDetected) > 1000)) {
            lastSpeechDetected = -1;
            [speechTask finish];
            return;
        }
        [speechRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer: buffer];
    }];

    [audioEngine prepare];
    [audioEngine startAndReturnError: &outError];
```

Comment: did you try out my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code we ended up with that works.

The key thing was to installTapOnBus() and then the magic code to detect the volume,

float volume = fabsf(*buffer.floatChannelData[0]);

```
-(void) doActualRecording {
    NSLog(@"doActualRecording");

    @try {
    //if (!recording) {
        if (audioEngine != NULL) {
            [audioEngine stop];
            [speechTask cancel];
            AVAudioInputNode* inputNode = [audioEngine inputNode];
            [inputNode removeTapOnBus: 0];
        }

        recording = YES;
        micButton.selected = YES;

        //NSLog(@"Starting recording...   SFSpeechRecognizer Available? %d", [speechRecognizer isAvailable]);
        NSError * outError;
        //NSLog(@"AUDIO SESSION CATEGORY0: %@", [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] category]);
        AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&outError];
        [audioSession setMode: AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement error:&outError];
        [audioSession setActive: true withOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&outError];

        SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest* speechRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];
        //NSLog(@"AUDIO SESSION CATEGORY1: %@", [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] category]);
        if (speechRequest == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to create SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest.");
            return;
        }

        speechDetectionSamples = 0;

        // This some how fixes a crash on iPhone 7
        // Seems like a bug in iOS ARC/lack of gc
        AVAudioEngine* temp = audioEngine;
        audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
        AVAudioInputNode* inputNode = [audioEngine inputNode];

        speechRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true;

        // iOS speech does not detect end of speech, so must track silence.
        lastSpeechDetected = -1;

        speechTask = [speechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest: speechRequest delegate: self];

        [inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize: 4096 format: [inputNode outputFormatForBus:0] block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer* buffer, AVAudioTime* when) {
            @try {
                long long millis = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
                if (lastSpeechDetected != -1 && ((millis - lastSpeechDetected) > 1000)) {
                    lastSpeechDetected = -1;
                    [speechTask finish];
                    return;
                }
                [speechRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer: buffer];

                //Calculate volume level
                if ([buffer floatChannelData] != nil) {
                    float volume = fabsf(*buffer.floatChannelData[0]);

                    if (volume >= speechDetectionThreshold) {
                        speechDetectionSamples++;

                        if (speechDetectionSamples >= speechDetectionSamplesNeeded) {

                            //Need to change mic button image in main thread
                            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {

                                [micButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"micRecording"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];

                            }];
                        }
                    } else {
                        speechDetectionSamples = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            @catch (NSException * e) {
                NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
            }
        }];

        [audioEngine prepare];
        [audioEngine startAndReturnError: &outError];
        NSLog(@"Error %@", outError);
    //}
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend low-pass filtering the power signal using `AVAudioRecorder` and a `NSTimer` for callback. This way you'll be able to detect when a certain threshold is reached in the audio recorder readings, and the low-pass filtering will help mitigating the noise.

In the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
    NSTimer *levelTimer;
    double lowPassResults;
}

- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer;
@end
```

In the .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // AVAudioSession already set in your code, so no need for these 2 lines.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];

    NSError *error;

    lowPassResults = 0;

    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

    if (recorder) {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];
        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.05 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    } else
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}


- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];

    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  

    NSLog(@"lowPassResults: %f",lowPassResults);

    // Use here a threshold value to stablish if there is silence or speech
    if (lowPassResults < 0.1) {
        NSLog(@"Silence");
    } else if(lowPassResults > 0.5){
        NSLog(@"Speech");
    }

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `AVCaptureAudioChannel`? Here's a link to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiochannel)

you have a `volume` property that provides the current volume (gain) of the channel.